# How to flag properties that are not safe in LINQ 2 entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The models in my software project can contain properties that are not mapped to the SQL and require the context query to be converted to an `IEnumerable` before using the property in a Where clause `(eg Display name => FirstName + Last Name)`. My team has started using `IQueryables` a lot more to retrieve data from our context layer and a common issue is accidentally using one of these computed properties in a where clause that will be converted to SQL. Is there an easy way to apply a warning or attribute to these properties so that they either don't show up as an option in an `IQueryable` Where or they throw a warning?

Comment: can only think of IDE solutions to this problem, i.e. the <summary> markup or the ObsoleteAttribute.

Comment: Something like the obsolete attribute would be ideal, the issue with that is it would show up everywhere.

Comment: Does it make sense to move  all of these computed properties to static helper methods like public static string DisplayName(this User user) => user.First. + user.Last ?

Comment: you can do that obviously, then you just have to invoke the function instead of calling the getter, and this will obviously take effect everywhere as well.

Comment: I would bite the bullet and remove these computed properties. With the adoption of `IQueryable` (100% in support of) you would be making use of view models to project to the views, so these computed properties migrate to the view model, or are expressed as the view model and populated from the `IQueryable`. Finding and fixing references to these properties should be quick and temporary obsolete function getters could be introduced to support the transition. (swapped in code not yet using `IQueryable` but wanting that computed value) Functions stand out in Linq far easier than properties.